# Internal Server Error Exception from Facebook Graph API

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch campaign,ad level information from Facebook Using Graph API.

Campaign level information is getting with zero error for all accounts.

But for the Ad Level info, I am not getting the entire data. The API returns only 50. Remaining ads are getting with an exception called "Internal Server Error".

I've been getting this problem all day for one particular account. Every other Account works fine.

Below is the HTTP response:

```
response = (okhttp3.Response) Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=500, message=Internal Server Error, 
url=https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_fbAccountId/ads?access_token=myAccessToken&fields=%5B%22account_id%22%2C%22campaign_id%22%2C%22adset_id%22%2C%22id%22%2C%22bid_amount%22%2C%22name%22%2C%22status%22%2C%22preview_shareable_link%22%5D&limit=25&after=QVFIUkFzZAVdONXEwMXc5NjlOWURwczRQN0V3QW12NndRa0I4ZAUxsSjNkZA0FTRHR1U1dnaTQ5MTh2QnJ3bzNwWkNPd21jbC1tbjRmZAF81WVBsc0txaERCMHVn}
```

Below is the code

```
public List facebookAdsSynchThroughJson(String accessTokens, Long advertAccId, Properties googleStructureProperties, byte isOnScheduler, String appSecret) {
        this.access_tokens = accessTokens;
        this.appSecret = appSecret;
        APIContext context = new APIContext(accessTokens, appSecret).enableDebug(true);
        List<FacebookAdsStructure> adsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String ads = "";
        JSONObject advertIdObj = null;
        JSONArray dataList = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = null;
        boolean cond = true;
        boolean success = false;
        int limitValue = 100;
        try {
            while (cond) {
                try {
                    AdAccount adAccount = new AdAccount(advertAccId, context).get().execute();
                    List adsFields = new ArrayList();
                    adsFields.add("account_id");
                    adsFields.add("campaign_id");
                    adsFields.add("adset_id");
                    adsFields.add("id");
                    adsFields.add("bid_amount");
                    adsFields.add("name");
                    adsFields.add("status");
                    adsFields.add("preview_shareable_link");
                    Map<String, Object> adsmap = new HashMap<>();
                    adsmap.put("fields", adsFields);
                    adsmap.put("limit", limitValue);
                    ads = adAccount.getAds().setParams(adsmap).execute().getRawResponseAsJsonObject().toString();
                } catch (APIException ex) {
                    LOGGER.info("Exception thrown when fetching ads for Account Id: " + advertAccId + " with limit value: " + limitValue);
                    LOGGER.error(ex);
                    if (limitValue > 6) {
                        cond = true;
                        limitValue = limitValue / 2;
                    } else {
                        cond = false;
                        success = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!ads.isEmpty()) {
                    cond = false;
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            if (success) {
                advertIdObj = new JSONObject(ads);
                dataList = advertIdObj.getJSONArray("data");
                mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                adsList = mapper.readValue(dataList.toString(), new TypeReference<List<FacebookAdsStructure>>() {
                });
                JsonObject obj;
                JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                JsonElement result = parser.parse(ads);
                obj = result.getAsJsonObject();
                int maxTries = 1;
                if (obj.has("data") && maxTries <= 5) {
                    while (obj.has("paging") && maxTries <= 5) {
                        JsonObject paging = obj.get("paging").getAsJsonObject();
                        if (paging.has("cursors")) {
                            JsonObject cursors = paging.get("cursors").getAsJsonObject();
                            String before = cursors.has("before") ? cursors.get("before").getAsString() : null;
                            String after = cursors.has("after") ? cursors.get("after").getAsString() : null;
                        }
                        String previous = paging.has("previous") ? paging.get("previous").getAsString() : null;
                        String next = paging.has("next") ? paging.get("next").getAsString() : "empty";
                        if (!next.equalsIgnoreCase("empty")) {
                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                    .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    .build();
                            Request request1 = new Request.Builder().url(next).get().build();
                            Response response = client.newCall(request1).execute();
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                maxTries = 1;
                                ads = response.body().string();
                                advertIdObj = new JSONObject(ads);
                                dataList = advertIdObj.getJSONArray("data");
                                mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                List<FacebookAdsStructure> adsLists = new ArrayList<>();
                                adsLists = mapper.readValue(dataList.toString(), new TypeReference<List<FacebookAdsStructure>>() {
                                });
                                adsList.addAll(adsLists);
                                LOGGER.info("Fetched the Ad Structure.." + adsList.size());
                                parser = new JsonParser();
                                result = parser.parse(ads);
                                obj = result.getAsJsonObject();
                            } else {
                                LOGGER.info("Exception in response when fetching ads for Account Id: " + advertAccId + " , error response message: " + response.message() + " and with limit value: " + limitValue);
                                maxTries++;
                                if (maxTries >= 6) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                try {
                                    LOGGER.info("Thread Sleeping For 2 Minutes - Started for fb se_account_id " + advertAccId + " and maxTries = " + maxTries);
                                    Thread.sleep(120000);
                                    LOGGER.info("Thread Sleeping For 2 Minutes - Completed for fb se_account_id " + advertAccId + " and maxTries = " + maxTries);
                                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                    Logger.getLogger(FacebookAccountStructureSyncThroughJson.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            obj = new JsonObject();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException | IOException | JSONException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex);
        }
        return adsList;
    }
```

If anybody knows anything about this issue, please help me.

Comment: Getting a 500 from the API is rare, usually it manages to respond with an exception that contains an error code and message. Can you log the exact value you get from the API for `next`, and see if that matches the request you see in the error message? When you take that exact value, and execute that request via your browser address bar or in Graph API Explorer, do you get a different result?

Comment: When I am executing the URL in browser also I am getting the same exception. But this exception is only for one account, the other accounts work fine.

Comment: I guess you best file a bug report with Facebook then, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs